# Python - simple interest

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code for myself that will give me an answer for simple interest, I will use same concept and later make compound interest. I am having trouble with my rate. when I do it as a percentage like

```
r = int(input("rate %: ")
```

and I type 5.4 it does not work so I tried it in a decimal form like this

```
 r = int(input("Rate 0."))
```

i get the same answer at end if i do 0.045 and 0.45 
so how do i fix this problem

here is my entire code

```
while True:
    while True:
            print('Working out for SIMPLE INTEREST')
            p = int(input("Principl:"))
            r = int(input("Rate 0."))
            t = int(input("Time yrs:"))
            i = p*r
            i = i*t
            a = p + i
            print("Interest = " + str(i))
            print("Accumalated = " + str(a))
            print(str(p) + ' x ' + str(r) + ' x ' + str(t) + ' = ' + str(i) + ' | ' + str(p) + ' + ' + str(i) + ' = ' + str(a))
```

Comment: What do you think `int(…)` does?

Comment: Replace `int` with `float`. And research about both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` converts the input string to an *integer*, which is a *whole* number like `4` or `5`. For `5.4`, you want a *floating point* number, which you can make using the `float` function:

```
r = float(input("rate %: "))
```

(For professional usage, you might even consider the arbitrary-precision [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) package, but it's probably overkill in your situation.)

Comment: Please help with another question i have 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49235379/how-to-remove-a-number-from-a-list-that-has-a-range-between-two-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution for Python program to calculate Simple Interest using ***Single Inheritance***.

```
class SimpleInterest:
    def __init__(self,principle,years,roi):
        self.principle = principle
        self.years = years
        self.roi = roi

class Interest(SimpleInterest):
    def calulate(self):
        si = (self.principle*self.years*self.roi)/100
        return si
    
principle = int(input())
years = int(input())
roi = int(input())

o = Interest(principle,years,roi)
si = o.calulate()
print("Principle amount:",principle)
print("No.Of.Years:",years)
print("Rate of interest:",roi)
print("Simple Interest:",si)
```

Answer (score -3):

It is because int does not support decimal numbers

So change `int(input('something...'))` to `input('sonething...')`

Comment: That will leave it as a `str`, which you cannot do arithmetic on.