# How to remove a number from a list that has a range between two numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take a random number from a list that goes from 0 to 9999. When I get that number, I want to compare it to a 4 digit number. Then, if it doesn't work, I want to **REMOVE** that random number from the list of 0 to 9999
e.g. it picks 9999 randomly and it compares to 3129 so it deletes it from the list and tries again list (range (0000, 9998))

```
lis = list(range(0000,9999))
import random
num = random.choice(lis)
while int(num) < pin or int(num) > pin:
    print(num)
    num = random.choice(lis)
    count = count + 1
    lis = lis.remove(num)
print('Got your pin in ' + str(count))
from time import sleep
sleep(4)
```

Comment: `lis = lis.remove(num)` is a big no no

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does append return none in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre i dont get what was in the question you provided? can my problem be solved?

Comment: `lis = lis.remove(num)` => `lis.remove(num)` that'll work much better

Comment: it is extremely unclear what you are trying to do and your code does not work well enough to offer any clarification. Can you give a concrete example that is manageable, e.g., with just 1 digit numbers? Something that covers as many different cases as possible in terms of matches, etc.

Comment: Did you mean to put `num = random.choice(lis)` inside the loop? It's very unclear.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thankyou that fixed my problem and i understand now that it is removing the number from the list.

Comment: then you can accept the duplicate "that solved my problem"

Comment: I meant: accept to close, not accept the answer.

Comment: Something different: The first time you get a random number from the list you run the while loop and pull another random number, but the first random number is not removed.

Comment: @L.S. not only that: the list is now `None` so the code breaks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yea my comment was to point out structural problems as an addition to the None problem you already pointed out :)

Comment: help! I accidentally looked at the code and now my eyes are bleeding!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 lis = lis.remove(num)
```

will set your list to 'None' because the remove method does not return anything. So just using

```
 lis.remove(num)
```

might solve your problem - whatever your problem is. Your post doesn't really contain a clear question.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
comp_number = 3129
def get_give_number_from_random_list(comp_number):
    numbers_list = list(range(9999))
    default = True
    while default:
        random_number = random.choice(numbers_list)
        if comp_number == random_number:
            print('Found the {} Number at index {}'.format(comp_number,numbers_list.index(random_number)))
            default = False
        else:
            numbers_list.remove(random_number)       
get_give_number_from_random_list(comp_number)
>>>Found the 3129 Number at index 2197
```

Answer (score -1):

I would also like to point out that your code does not take into account `0000` to `0999` combinations.

This is because python will simply count from `0` to `9999`

You are also including single, double and triple numbers eg `7`, `99`, `167`

You can prepare the list a little better and search using `strings` rather than `int`.

```
pin = '0001' # Search using a string
lis = ['{0:04}'.format(num) for num in range(0, 10000)] #use string foramtting to add the 0's
lis = [x for x in lis if len(str(x)) == 4] # take out any numbers that are less than 4 digits long
print(lis[0:10]) #check the first 10 items in the list
```